# Play 1.2.5 Application deployment on heroku "Oops. conf/routes or conf/application.conf missing."

Tags: heroku, playframework

I have a play 1.2.5 app and want to deploy it somewhere (so i can register it for some OAuth Callbacks). I am trying to push it to heroku but i get the following error

```
-----> Play! app detected
-----> Installing OpenJDK 1.6...done
-----> WARNING: Play! version not specified in dependencies.yml. Default version: 1.2.4 being used....
-----> Installing Play! 1.2.4.....
-----> done
-----> Installing ivysettings.xml..... done
-----> Building Play! application...
       ~        _            _ 
       ~  _ __ | | __ _ _  _| |
       ~ | '_ \| |/ _' | || |_|
       ~ |  __/|_|\____|\__ (_)
       ~ |_|            |__/   
       ~
       ~ play! 1.2.4, http://www.playframework.org
       ~
       1.2.4
       Building Play! application at directory ./
       Resolving dependencies: .play/play dependencies ./ --forProd --forceCopy --silent -Duser.home=/tmp/build_ev7rk9y0hage 2>&1
       ~ !! /tmp/build_ev7rk9y0hage/conf/dependencies.yml does not exist
       ~
       ~ Done!
       ~
       Precompiling: .play/play precompile ./ --silent 2>&1
       ~ Oops. conf/routes or conf/application.conf missing.
       ~ /tmp/build_ev7rk9y0hage does not seem to host a valid application.
       ~
 !     Failed to build Play! application
 !     Cleared Play! framework from cache

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Play! app
```

I have been following this guide:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play
To be more specific;

1. `heroku login`
2. Set Applications sependencies to play 1.2.5
3. Set up .gitignore file
4. Created Procfile with `web:    play run --http.port=$PORT $PLAY_OPTS` in project root folder
5. commited to the local git repo
6. `heroku create`
7. `git push heroku master`

I have no idea how to fix this and neither stackoverflow nor googlegroups (and some other sources) could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i resolved the issue, the problem was that we were using git already and the repository was initialized in the parent folder of the play project `parent/projRoot/`, so I guess heroku was looking for the files in the wrong places and could not build because of that. With a new git repo that was initialized in `projRoot/` the everything worked just fine.

**Update**
To deploy a play app from a subfolder i found these solutions:

[Deploy Play app on Heroku from a subdirectory of git repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14286266/deploy-play-app-on-heroku-from-a-subdirectory-of-git-repo)

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/Gk9nfNSUzQs