# Do I need to track a directory to be able to subtree and push it to a different remote branch?

Tags: git, yeoman, git-subtree

I use one repo with `develop` and `release` branches for a Yeoman project.

Simplified, my directory tree looks like this:

```
root git directory
├── app 
└── dist (the build folder)
```

With Grunt.js I build my app straight into `dist`.

I would like to use `git subtree push --prefix dist origin release` to conveniently update `release` with a new build - as detailed in the [Yeoman documentation](http://yeoman.io/deployment.html).

Do I need to track, commit and push the `dist` directory in the `develop` branch at all times to use this method?

I would like to know as well - since on my own, I could not make the above work conveniently - would a submodule tracking the `release` branch be a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a much better and easier solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19374618/1049693