# How do I force a subtree push to overwrite remote changes?

Tags: git, yeoman, git-subtree

We use a subtree deployment a lá [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490) to deploy a subdirectory of our [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) project. In our case, the branch is called *production*, not *gh-pages*.

This worked perfectly until yesterday when the Git server rejected the command `git subtree push --prefix dist origin production`, saying

```
 ! [rejected]        9fe1683aa574eae33ee6754aad702488e0bd37df -> production (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab.sdstate.edu:web-and-new-media/graduation2015.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart.
```

If I switch to the production branch locally (which is clean), `git pull` returns `Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/production'.` even if I use the `--rebase` option.

I can see the contents of the production branch on the server through our web UI and there's nothing there that shouldn't be, just the compiled output of our `dist` directory like I'd expect.

To that end, it seems like I should safely be able to force an overwrite of these files, but how? `git subtree push` doesn't have a `--force` option.

Comment: The command `git subtree split --prefix dist origin production` also fails: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'origin': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: Well, now I'm really stumped. I ran `git subtree pull --prefix dist origin production`, which did leave me with a merge conflict related to the code I'd changed so I fixed that and ran `git subtree push --prefix dist origin production` again...only to fail with the same error again.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

The trick was to chain the subtree split into a forced push:

```
git push origin `git subtree split --prefix dist master`:production --force
```

I got this from the Addendum of http://clontz.org/blog/2014/05/08/git-subtree-push-for-deployment/, who actually references [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13403588/1457116) answer on Stack Overflow. I had skimmed this one earlier but Steve Clontz's post made it click for me.

Comment: This solution failed with "fatal: ambiguous argument 'publish-dev': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Comment: Did anyone solve the fatal ambiguous argument issue?

Comment: For fatal ambiguous argument, use -b prefix for branch name

Comment: FYI: When used with Github Pages, this resets your custom domain name.

Comment: @ConstantMeiring Yeah it appears that you have to manually duplicate the CNAME file (which contains the domain name).

Comment: Could you explain more about what origin, master, & production are?

Comment: unknown option prefix

Comment: Initial source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12644855/how-do-i-reset-a-heroku-git-repository-to-its-initial-state - For the sole purpose of *enforcing git push* you may want to replace `production` with `master` too. So it should rather be: `git push origin \`git subtree split --prefix dist master\`:master --force` - the parameter `origin` you can also replace with your Git repository URL if you're here purely for Heroku - hope that helps

Comment: this just deletes the `gh-pages` on me.

Comment: if you see "cannot delete master branch", then make sure you are running the command from repository root

Answer (score 26):

I've just enhanced the answer of [ele](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33178233/5506730) adding generic expressions `<>` to make it more clear:

```
git push <remote> `git subtree split --prefix <local-folder> <local-branch>`:<remote-branch> --force
```

Example values

`<remote>`

```
origin
other-origin-name
https://github.com/full-url/of-repo
```

`<local-folder>`

Local folder path relative to repo root e.g.: `/dist` (you need to execute this command in root btw)

`<remote-branch>`

```
master
any-other-branchname
```

Comment: If you have a server trying pull these changes, `git pull origin <branch>` won't work. But this will: `git fetch --all && git reset --hard origin/<branch>`

Comment: Warning: I must've put in the wrong branches when running this command because it deleted my remote branch. It was easy to push my subtree branch after I deleted it and wasn't a problem in the end, but there may be cases where you don't want your remote branch deleted... so be careful!

Answer (score 4):

## There is a simpler solution

### This always works for me.

1. Set up a bash script which helps you do the following:

```sh
cd dist
git init
git add .
git commit -am "deploy"
git push --force <remote URL> master
rm -rf .git
cd ..
```

This creates a new git repository in the subdirectory you specify and force pushes everything from there.

2. profit

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a solution that is much more simple.

Source: https://gist.github.com/cobyism/4730490#gistcomment-2337463

### Setup

```
$ rm -rf dist
$ echo "dist/" >> .gitignore
$ git worktree add dist gh-pages
```

### Making changes

```
$ make # or what ever you run to populate dist
$ cd dist
$ git add --all
$ git commit -m "$(git log '--format=format:%H' master -1)"
$ git push origin production --force
$ cd ..
```