# I am getting an error when I run git subtree push --prefix dist heroku master telling me to run git pull

Tags: node.js, git, heroku, vue.js, package.json

I am trying to use this tutorial https://medium.com/@sagarjauhari/quick-n-clean-way-to-deploy-vue-webpack-apps-on-heroku-b522d3904bc8 so that I only push the dist folder to heroku. I am using the following code:

```
"deploy": "git subtree push --prefix dist heroku master"
```

so when I am satisfied with my changes that i have made locally, i do the following.

```
npm run build 
git add -A
git commit -m "message"
git push
npm run deploy
```

then i get an error message that reads:

> ! [rejected]        a1869b5091eac1a50721d4c0cb8385f48338d8d9 -> master (non-fast-forward)
>   error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/foobar'
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
>   hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
>   hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

What am I doing wrong? If I run `git push heroku` at this point, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick (and potentially destructive) fix, you can force the subtree to push. Note that this will **destroy any data** on Heroku that you don't have locally, and you **canot undo this change**.

To do this, run the following command:

```
git push heroku `git subtree split --prefix dist master`:master --force
```

and run `npm run deploy` again.

Please let me know if that helps.

Referenced:

[How do I force a subtree push to overwrite remote changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33172857/how-do-i-force-a-subtree-push-to-overwrite-remote-changes) and http://clontz.org/blog/2014/05/08/git-subtree-push-for-deployment/